# New custom cell from XIB causing key value coding-compliant for the key ...?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I've a custom table view cell that I created using XIB:

[image]

I've also linked up the XIB file with my custom UITableView cell.

But now when I try to load the cell in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` with the following codes:

```
MyCustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:cell options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:1];
    }
```

I'll get a `[<NSObject 0x8a5b970> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key hitMeButton.`

I have been searching online and one of the possible reasons might be that the XIB is not linked to the IBOutlet, I've checked so that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I just solved the problem, but I'm not sure if that is the most appropriate way.

```
if (cell == nil) {

MyCustomTableViewCell *aCell = [[MyCustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

 NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:aCell options:nil];

cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

}
```

Answer (score 32):

The real problem is how you've linked the outlets. 
You have to link your Outlets from the TableViewCell to labels in your cell (you probably linked the label at the File owner's)

Here some more explicative images : 

**This is ok**
[image]

**This is wrong**
[image]

Comment: I can't understand why the accepted answer has a result of `-1` and my is not accepted but received 18 points :P

Comment: Saw this as I was looking for the best nsunknownkeyexception thread to post just this solution, i.e. connect to the CELL not the file's owner. Wild guess on my part, but you beat me to posting it. :)